# Jquery/ajax Looping SetTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi I'm stuck on my setTimeout function. What i'm trying to do is to loop my setTimeout for my retrieve conversation function.. I have tried this on setInterval but using setInterval is a badnews for my application which is why I switch to setTimeout.. But I cant seem to figure out how to make the setTimeout work again after its done loading.. here is what I have tried so far and still trying to make it work at the moment..

Javascript:

```
id = setTimeout(function()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "includes/handlechat.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result)
        {
            $("#clog").empty();
            $.each(result, function(rowKey, row) 
            {
                $("#clog")
                    .append('<p ><h4>'+ row.username +':</h4>' + row.message_content + '</p>' );
            });
        },
        complete: function () 
        { 
            clearTimeout(id);
        }
    })
}, 1101);
```

Any tips or suggestion ?

Comment: This script is working fine on setInterval FYI no errors or such only bugs which is I find it insignificant to my main question =))

Comment: FYI, `clearTimeout` is only needed if there are multiple calls to `setTimeout` before the first one is completed, and you want to prevent multiple executions of the delayed code.

Comment: Using setinterval may be bad - you might end up queueing multiple calls to handlechat.php at the same time (due to delays responding from server load).  In this case you're pouring fuel onto the fire by queueing more requests to an already overloaded server.  It's better to go along the route you're proposing with your setTimeout call.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put the code in a function and call it in the success or complete handler:

```
function load() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "includes/handlechat.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',  
            success: function (result) {
                $("#clog").empty();
                $.each(result, function (rowKey, row) {
                    $("#clog").append('<p ><h4>' + row.username + ':</h4>' + row.message_content + '</p>'); 
                }); 
            },
            complete: load
        });
    }, 1101);
}
load();
```

You can also use an IIFE to avoid creating another binding in the current environment:

```
(function load() {
   // setTimeout here
}());
```

Comment: If the ajax call fails temporarily, success will not get called, and the loop will stop.  I'd advise swapping to use the xhr return from $.ajax, and use .done() to handle the data and an .always() to start the loop again.

Comment: true, it makes sense to move the call to `complete`.

Comment: Hi I have tried your code suggestion and it worked and loaded the chat conversation.. but I when I tried clicking on other users from my UI it loads the conversation for that user then reverts to the 1st user's conversation and now both of them loads alternately.. is the code the reason why it became like that?

Comment: Most likely. It will run in an endless "loop", sending whatever `data` refers to. Since you didn't provide any context of your code, there is not much more I can say about it.

Comment: This actually solved my problem and my issue earlier was because I forgot to include the variable data inside the function sorry about that.. Paul's suggestion was also used and worked but your code is much near to what I want.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like this.

```
function getChatMessages() {
    $.ajax({
        // your params here
    }).done(function (data) {
        // do something with the data
    }).always(function () {
        window.setTimeout(getChatMessages, 1101);
    });
}

getChatMessages();
```

Purpose of the '.always' is so you don't get some error on fetching messages (timeout, some kind of 500, etc) that breaks your loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
 url: "includes/handlechat.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json', 
            success:function(data){
 //your succesfull code
            },
            error:function(){
            //code when time is out
            },
            timeout:10000  // will return the code in error after 10 seconds
        });
```