# Timeout an HTML markup in AJAX Success

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to set the timeout when ajax Success is triggered. So after 2 seconds lets say, I need that success markup to disappear.

This is my code,

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'process/register/registerDB.php',
    success : function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      timer = setTimeout(successNotification, 2000);
    }
});

function successNotification {
  $('#alert-box')
    .html('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">User <b>'
          + newUserArr["fullname"]
          + '</b> Successfully Submitted</div>');
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery/ajax Looping SetTimeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23050077/jquery-ajax-looping-settimeout)

Comment: use can use animate css property to hide div tag with some duration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function myfunc() {
    $.ajax({
        // your params here
    }).done(function (data) {
        // do something with the data
    }).always(function () {
        window.setTimeout(getChatMessages, 1101);
    });
}
myfunc();
```

Purpose of the `.always` is so you don't get some error on fetching messages.

Answer (score 1):

In Ajax you prefer setTimeout is bit different example :

```
setTimeout(function () { successNotification(); }, 2000);
```

Use this it might be helpful

Comment: you can also use setTimeout(successNotification, 2000)

Comment: I think youre mistaken what my question is. So after the function, it shows successNotification() then after 2 seconds, the markup inside successNotofication should disappear

Comment: Yes I understood your question. Actually ajax requests may complete at any time. so it won't exactly be once every 2 seconds using setInterval. You could also call setTimout in the successNotification callback to chain the calls.

Answer (score 1):

Please replace timer = setTimeout(successNotification, 2000); to timer = setTimeout("successNotification", 2000);

the difference is only function in quotes, the successNotification message will call after 2 second.