# How can I disable a getJSON request if it hasn't completed in one second and move onto the next one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.getJSON('https://example.com', function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    });
}, 1000);
```

Currently every second, my script outputs data from a JSON file in the console log.

However if it does not do this in time, the requests build up and a huge backlog appears! How can I cancel the current getJSON request and move onto the next one if it has not completed in the time frame?

Comment: Convert your `$.getJSON` to a regular `$.ajax` call, it has a `timeout` setting: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. Another approach would be to do something as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23050092/189362

Comment: Don't. Canceling the request won't stop the server from processing it, or from a backlog being created. you're better off not sending another until the previous completes.

Comment: agree with @Bjorn `getJSON` is just shorthand  for ajax

Comment: shouldnt be downvoting the guy for writing wrong code, his question was clear and the code was provided that was concerned

Comment: @KevinB The problem with that is the information changes rapidly and I might miss something.

Comment: @JugglingBob then ajax isn't the right tool.

Comment: Canceling a request that is taking too long then sending another is more likely to take longer than the original request you sent that is taking too long.

Comment: Also, one second is an awfully short timeout...

Comment: a 30 second timeout plus long polling would be faster than a 1 second interval and possibly require less resources. but a websocket or server sent events would be even better.

Comment: Also, if you're polling an endpoint every 1 second, maybe you dont really want ajax at all. Could be that a service worker or a websocket is more suited to your needs.

Comment: Never loop ajax using loop/setInterval - instead call again in the done/success - also don't hammer a server that does not respond fast. There is perhaps a reason for it not responding and you just made it worse

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `xhr` object and kill it with `abort` evertime.

```js
var xhr = $.getJSON('https://example.com', function(data) {
    console.log(data)
});

//kill the request after 500ms
setTimeout(xhr.abort, 500);
```